# How to write conditions and Tolerance in GEKKO?

Tags: python, matlab, gekko

Need help for the following conditions to be implemented in GEKKO python.

1. For Matlab, i have the following conditions

   if t<15

   x1 = 1e-7;

   else x1 = 0;

   end

For python I have written the code as

```
m.time = np.linspace(0,60)
t = m.Var(0)
m.Equation(t.dt()==1)
x1 = m.if2(t-15,1e-7,0)
```

But that didn't work. Basically x1 is my input and I want that x1 to be available for 15min only, after that it is 0. Please let me know the solution to this.

2.effect=min((0.2*x17+0.8*x19)/APequil, 1)
in Matlab

In python I have used the following
effect=m.min2(((0.2*x17+0.8*x19)/APequil),1)

Please check if its okay? As removing min2 is not affecting my solution.

3. In matlab, have used
   options=odeset('InitialStep',0.0001,'RelTol',1e-09),

how to use the same in GEKKO python? As I have successful solution in matlab, but the same output is not achieved in Python, i think it is due to this tolerance value or what?

Answer (score 1):

Use a list of values to give different values based on the time or position.

```py
x1 = m.Param([0 if i<15 else 1e-7 for i in range(101)])
```

Use a slack variable `s` to clip the value of `effect` at an upper bound of `1`. This is more efficient than using the `if2()` or `if3()` function.

```py
effect = m.Var(ub=1)
s = m.Var(lb=0)
m.Minimize(s)
m.Equation(effect==x1*3e7-s)
```

The tolerance can be set with `m.options.RTOL` (equation residual tolerance) and `m.options.OTOL` (objective tolerance). Here is an example:

[image: example problem]

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
t  = np.linspace(0,100,101); m.time = t
x1 = m.Param([0 if i<15 else 1e-7 for i in range(101)])
effect = m.Var(ub=1)
s = m.Var(lb=0)
m.Minimize(s)
m.Equation(effect==x1*3e7-s)

m.options.IMODE=6
m.options.RTOL = 1e-6
m.options.OTOL = 1e-6
m.solve()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t,x1,'k--',label='x1')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(t,effect,'r--',label='Effect')
plt.plot(t,s,'b.-',label='Slack')
plt.legend(); plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

There are [additional examples](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/GekkoPythonOptimization) and [documentation](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that can also help.

Comment: Thank you sir. I understood the rest part except  how this is implemented from python effect=m.min2(((0.2*x17+0.8*x19)/APequil),1)
To 
effect = m.Var(ub=1)
s = m.Var(lb=0)
m.Minimize(s)
m.Equation(effect==x1*3e7-s)

Comment: The slack variable `s` allows the equation to be feasible even when `0.2*x17+0.8*x19)/APequil` is greater than 1. Here is more information on slack variables: https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/SlackVariables  For your problem, it would be `effect = 0.2*x17+0.8*x19)/APequil - s` with bound `effect.upper=1`, `s.lower=0`, and `m.Minimize(s)`.

Comment: The model has 21 ODEs. x1 is the input for 15 min. Now as i added                                                                                             t  = np.linspace(0,100,101); m.time = t x1 = m.Param([0 if i<15 else 1e-7 for i in range(101)]). plot (t,x1) is working fine. But plot(t,x2), where x2 to x21 are already defined in my code is giving error as File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 501, in _plot_args raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (101,) and (1,)

Comment: Could you post your code with a new question?

Comment: Have Posted the matlab code, with an expectation to use fmincon solver after looking one of your video regarding the same. As I am a novice in the field, it is getting difficult for me to solve my issue..Regret the inconvenience and appreciate your help sir. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69064579/optimization-using-fmincon-ode-matlab