# Optimization using fmincon ODE Matlab

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

The problem is to find the optimum(maximum) value of x3 in range of (-8e-4 to 2e-4) by varying kst,x1,x5 and xo)

```matlab
x5=5    %Input 2 (Input 2 is a state variable and could vary in range of 4 to 15 while performing 
                  optimization)
kst=1   %Input 3 (Input 3 is in terms of rate constant, it could vary from 0.1 to 2)
xo=4    %Input 4 (Input 4 is a state variable and could vary in range of 4 to 10)
x1=1e-7 %Input 1 could vary from 1e-9 to 1e-6
```

1. Script file

```matlab
    function rest = Scrpt1(t,X)
    x2 = X(1); 
    x3 = X(2); 
    
    %Parameters
    
    if t<15
    
    x1 = 1e-7; %Input 1 could vary from 1e-9 to 1e-6
    
    else x1 = 0;
    
    end
    
    x5=5 %Input 2 (Input 2 is a state variable and could vary in range of 4 to 15 while performing optimization)
    
    kst=1 %Input 3 (Input 3 is in terms of rate constant, it could vary from 0.1 to 2)

    xo=4 %Input 4 (Input 4 is a state variable and could vary in range of 4 to 10)
    
    k1 = 6e7;

    km1 = 0.20;

    km4 = 0.003;

    k3 = 2500.00;

    k4 = km4/9;

    km3 = km1;

    LAP=1.5

% Differential equations

    dx2dt = km1*x3 + km3*LAP - k1*x1*x2 + km4*x3 - k4*x2;

    dx3dt = k1*x1*x2 - km1*(x3+x5+xo) - k3*x3*kst;

    rest = [dx2dt; dx3dt];

    end
```

2. Function file for ODE solution

```matlab
    options = odeset('InitialStep',0.0001,'RelTol',1e-09);
    
    [T,Y]=ode15s(@Scrpt1,[0 60],[9e-13,0],options);
    
    X3= Y(:,2);
    
    plot(T,X3)
```

How to use fmincon or any other optimization solver for this to solve the mentioned optimization problem of finding maximum value of x3. For which values of x5,kst,xo,x1 we get maximum x3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must add the values you want wo optimie as parameters of your coupled diffrential equations:

```matlab
function rest = Scrpt1(t,X,X_opt)
    
    x5=X_opt(1);
    kst=X_opt(2);
    xo=X_opt(3);
    x1=X_opt(4);  
    x2 = X(1); 
    x3 = X(2); 
    
    %Parameters
    
    if t>=15
    x1 = 0;  
    end
    
    k1 = 6e7;
    km1 = 0.20;
    km4 = 0.003;
    k3 = 2500.00;
    k4 = km4/9;
    km3 = km1;
    LAP=1.5;

% Differential equations

    dx2dt = km1*x3 + km3*LAP - k1*x1*x2 + km4*x3 - k4*x2;
    dx3dt = k1*x1*x2 - km1*(x3+x5+xo) - k3*x3*kst;
    rest = [dx2dt; dx3dt];
    end
```

then you have to wirte a wrapper function you want to minimize. Because you want to maxmize x3 you have to add an minus to your objective value.

```matlab
function max_X3=fun(X_opt) 
    tspan=[0 60];
    y0=[9e-13,0];
    options = odeset('InitialStep',0.0001,'RelTol',1e-09);
    
    [~,y] = ode15s(@(t,y) Scrpt1(t,y,X_opt), tspan, y0,options);
    
    max_X3=-max(y(:,2));
end
```

Finally you can use fmincon like this:

```matlab
% x5, kst, xo, x1
initial_search_point=[5, 1, 4, 1e-7]
lower_bounds=[4, 0.1, 4, 1e-9]
upper_bounds=[15, 2, 10, 1e-6]

fmincon(@fun,initial_search_point,[],[],[],[], lower_bounds,upper_bounds)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have really explained it clearly :)

Comment: @ Erysol, I would like to know how can we put an upper and lower bound for the function we are supposed to find maximum? As  I have mentioned, I want to find maximum within lower and upper range of (-8e-4 to 2e-4) in Matlab.

Comment: The lower and upper bound constrain the variables you want to optimize not the function itself. You wrote: "input 2 is a state variable and could vary in range of 4 to 15 while performing optimization". That's what the first upper and lower bound mean.

Comment: Yes, that i know. The problem is with different initial search points, i am getting different optimization output combinations. The purpose is to find the maximum output x3  that falls within the range of (-8e-4 to 2e-4). So how to choose a good initial search points?

Comment: This is a problem of any numerical global optimization method. The solution is simply to try a bunch of starting points and select the highst maximum that you find. Matlabs 'GlobalSearch' object does that for you, or you code this on your own (should be easy enogh). If selecting random points isn't good enogh (e.g. your are limiet by compuation time) you can generate evenly distributed starting points with an latin-hypercube-design or a halton set. But I think random selection is just fine for your problem.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Could you please answer this question as I need a good clarification https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70677683/fmincon-of-matlab-a-global-optimization-solver-or-local-optimization-solver-als

Comment: Could you please answer this question as I need a good clarification https://stackoverflow.com/q/76293816/16739361

Answer (score 1):

Below is a solution in [Gekko](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DynamicEstimation) that can run in Python or with a [Python interface to MATLAB](https://apmonitor.com/che263/index.php/Main/MatlabCallsPython).

[image: x3 maximize]

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

n = 121; t = np.linspace(0,60,n)

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = t

k1 = 6e7; km1 = 0.20; km4 = 0.003;
k3 = 2500.00; k4 = km4/9;
km3 = km1; LAP=1.5

x5  = m.FV(value=5,lb=4,ub=15);  x5.STATUS = 1
kst = m.FV(value=1,lb=0.1,ub=2); kst.STATUS = 1
xo  = m.FV(value=4,lb=4,ub=10);  xo.STATUS = 1
x1  = m.FV(value=[1e-17 if t[i]<15 else 0 for i in range(n)],\
           lb=1e-9,ub=1e-6)
x2,x3 = m.Array(m.Var,2)
x3.value = -0.00032
x3.lower = -8e-4
x3.upper = 2e-4

m.Equations([x2.dt()==km1*x3+km3*LAP-k1*x1*x2+km4*x3-k4*x2,
             x3.dt()==k1*x1*x2-km1*(x3+x5+xo)-k3*x3*kst])
m.Maximize(x3)

m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.options.IMODE  = 6
m.solve()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(m.time,x3)
plt.show()
```

The initial condition for `x2` and `x3` are not defined.

```
 Number of state variables:            483
 Number of total equations: -          480
 Number of slack variables: -            0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :              3
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Dynamic Control with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
 
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
    0  4.99217E+02  2.99935E-01
    1  6.07645E-02  4.31439E-05
    2  3.25294E-02  3.04712E-05
    3  3.41027E-02  8.96081E-05
    4  3.31615E-02  2.48287E-06
    5  3.31615E-02  2.22045E-16
    6  3.31615E-02  2.22045E-16
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   2.189999999245629E-002 sec
 Objective      :   3.316154172805905E-002
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, now I am clear about the steps in GEKKO.

Comment: Could you please answer this question as I need a good clarification https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70677683/fmincon-of-matlab-a-global-optimization-solver-or-local-optimization-solver-als

Comment: I need to focus my responses on [gekko] tagged questions. I receive many requests for support each week. Here is something that may help: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DynamicEstimation Good luck with your application!